# shell globbing doesn't work the way I expect

Tags: linux, shell

I retired several years ago and back when I was working I was using Linux, Solaris, and SunOS. As I remember, if I did

```
mkdir x
cd x
echo hello > x*
```

The shell would respond with something like "x*: no match" and the echo command was not executed. But now when I do it on Debian Linux it creates the file x*. I tried it with both /bin/bash and /bin/sh; same results.

So then I stumbled across failglob and shopt.  Apparently failglob is not set on debian linux so I put this in my .bashrc file:

```
shopt -s failglob
```

Is having failglob unset normal behavior? Is it peculiar to Debian, or Linux?

Comment: Are you sure you remember the error message from sh/bash specifically? It actually sounds distinctly like something from csh (C shell) instead.

Comment: It was a long time ago, before linux became even slightly popular.  But yes, csh definitely gave an error message like that.  Also the Bourne shell, what was /bin/sh back then.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX [states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03) the following:

> If the pattern does not match any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern string shall be left unchanged.

Therefore, this behavior is POSIX compliant and would therefore be the default in sh mode.  It may be that your shell was configured differently, either by you or by your distro, for interactive use in the past (or possibly that bash used to have non-POSIX defaults).  dash, which is the default `/bin/sh` for Debian, doesn't appear to ever had this behavior, although it may be that bash was the default `/bin/sh` at the time you were working on it.

Note also that this behavior is the default for zsh in zsh mode (the option `nomatch`), but is disabled in sh and ksh modes (since it's not POSIX compliant).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It was a long time ago that I'm remembering this from so it's good to know that they're POSIX compliant, even though it's surprising to me (shows how long I've been away from unix).